# How to Get Value Out from the Tkinter Slider ("Scale")?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

So, here is the code I have, and as I run it, the value of the slider bar appears above the slider, I wonder is there a way to get that value out?  Maybe let a=that value. ;)

```
from Tkinter import *

control = Tk()
control.geometry("350x200+100+50")

scale = Scale(control,orient=HORIZONTAL,length=300,width=20,sliderlength=10,from_=0,to=1000,tickinterval=100)
scale.pack()

control.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 16):

To get the value as it is modified, associate a function with the parameter `command`. This function will receive the current value, so you just work with it. Also note that in your code you have `cline3 = Scale(...).pack()`. `cline3` is always None in this case, since that is what `pack()` returns.

```
import Tkinter

def print_value(val):
    print val

root = Tkinter.Tk()

scale = Tkinter.Scale(orient='horizontal', from_=0, to=128, command=print_value)
scale.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: great,thanks ans also how do you assign the value of "val" to a variable, since I am making this as a speed control bar in my program, I need a variable ("speed") with the value of val in other part of my program. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: It seems in that case you just want to call `scale.get()`. Or maybe do you want to modify a value somewhere else whenever the value of the scale widget is modified ? In that case, in the `print_value` function you just do exactly that. I would need to know more details about your current problem to help further.

Comment: you can write your code inside the function `print_value` so that the variable `val` is accessible for you.

Answer (score 13):

Call the `.get()` method on the slider to read the current value:

```
print scale.get()
```

See the [Tkinter Scale widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/scale.htm) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Idk if you have finally solved or not given age: but ive done a similar app for robot control. Basic code after gui was declared and initialized, and scale programmed:      scale(blahblahblah)
    Scale.grid(blahblah)

```
Def forward():
    motor1.forward(scale.get())
    motor2.backward(scale.get())
```

Bear in mind: speed value requires percentage of 1, so set the scale to: from 0 to 1 with intervals being either .01 or .1(i used .1 for 10ths of my speed variable)