# Why Do I get an error when I try to get tkinter slider value?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, slider

I am trying to read the value from a tkinter slider and use it by some functions as following

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog, Label
import cv2
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

panelA = None
panelB = None

def av_blur(k):
    global panelB
    dst_img = cv2.imread('result_img.jpg',0)
    dst_img = cv2.blur(dst_img,(5,5))
    k = int(k)
    dst_img = cv2.blur(dst_img, (k, k))
    ...

def av_blur(k):
    global panelB
    dst_img = cv2.imread('result_img.jpg',0)
    dst_img = cv2.blur(dst_img,(5,5))
    k = int(k)
    dst_img = cv2.blur(dst_img, (k, k))
    ...
root = Tk()
opt_frame = Frame(root)
opt_frame.pack( side=LEFT ,expand=1, fill='both')

img_frame = Frame(root)
img_frame.pack( side=RIGHT ,expand=1, fill='both')

src_frame = Frame(img_frame,background="black")
src_frame.pack( side=TOP ,expand=1, fill='both')

dst_frame = Frame(img_frame,background="white")
dst_frame.pack( side=BOTTOM ,expand=1, fill='both')
#
# Defining Blur functions
#
blur_sel = IntVar()
br_frame = Frame(opt_frame,width=200, height=100)
blur_sel = IntVar()
blur_sel = 4
blur_rad1 = Radiobutton(br_frame, text='Average Blur', value=0,variable=blur_sel,command=av_blur)
blur_rad2 = Radiobutton(br_frame, text='Gaussian Blur', value=1,variable=blur_sel,command=ga_blur)
blur_rad3 = Radiobutton(br_frame, text='Median Blur', value=2,variable=blur_sel)
blur_rad1.pack(side="left", expand=True)
blur_rad2.pack(side="left", expand=True)
blur_rad3.pack(side="left", expand=True)
br_frame.pack(anchor='w',side="top", fill=None,expand=0)
blur_slide = Scale(opt_frame, from_=1, to=32, length=600,tickinterval=4,command=av_blur,orient=HORIZONTAL)
blur_slide.pack(anchor="w", padx=10, pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

The problem whenever I try to reas the slider value named `k` I keep getting the following error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: av_blur() missing 1 required positional argument: 'k'
```

### Simple example

I tried this simple example and still getting the same thing:

```
def open_file():
    ...

def blurring():
    print(scale.get())

root = Tk()
opt_frame = Frame(root)
opt_frame.pack( side=LEFT ,expand=1, fill='both')

img_frame = Frame(root)
img_frame.pack( side=RIGHT ,expand=1, fill='both')

src_frame = Frame(img_frame,background="black")
src_frame.pack( side=TOP ,expand=1, fill='both')

dst_frame = Frame(img_frame,background="white")
dst_frame.pack( side=BOTTOM ,expand=1, fill='both')
#
# Defining main window menu
#
menu = Menu(root)
new_item = Menu(menu)
new_item.add_command(label='Open File', command=open_file)
new_item.add_separator()
new_item.add_command(label='Save File')
new_item.add_separator()
new_item.add_command(label='Exit')
menu.add_cascade(label='File', menu=new_item)
root.config(menu=menu)
#
# Defining Blur functions
#
scale = Scale(opt_frame,orient='horizontal', from_=0, to=128, command=blurring)
scale.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

But it worked when I tried the example in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14511723/11884974).

Comment: the error is self explanatory. You need to pass a value to the function `av_blur` as you have defined it as `def av_blur(k):`

Comment: Yes I got that But How I am new with tkinter

Comment: change `def blurring():` to `def blurring(value):` Scale is already sending a value to the function so to handle this. Then change `print(scale.get())` to `print(value)`. You will see that you are getting the value passed automatically by Scale. Some methods will send arguments by default.

Comment: @Mike-SMT: I tried that and I got `ypeError: get_value() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given`

Comment: Do not use get. Scale is already passing the value to the function. Just print the value directly.

Comment: Finally ...  you are GREAT I will post the answer and tag you in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplifying your 2nd example you need to have an argument handled in your function that is trying to get the value of Scale.

Scale is already passing an argument so you dont need to write a lambda to manage this.

Simple do this:

```
import tkinter as tk


def blurring(value):
    print(value)

root = tk.Tk()
scale = tk.Scale(root, orient='horizontal', from_=0, to=128, command=blurring)
scale.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Results:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the `command` option for `blur_slide`, change it either:

```
...command = lambda: av_blue(k) # where k is the value you pass to the function
```

**EDIT**

The `lambda` function is used here to pass the argument `k` when the slider is clicked or changes position.

If `k` is a computed value, then the computation has to be done in a different function (placed under the `command` option) as:

```
...command = precompute

def precomute():
    # calculate k here
    av_blur(k)
```

or change the function defintion to:

```
def av_blur():
    # your code here
```

Comment: I would explain why you use a lambda here. It will help the OP.

Comment: still getting the same  problem!!

Comment: @nechi I fail to understand why you are getting the same problem

Comment: I tried a simple example without frames just creating a scale widget and print the values and it works fine. but it does not make sense